# Javascript - Dispatch built-in events

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I know that we can use `element.dispatchEvent(custom_event)` to dispatch a custom event that we defined. 
My question is how to dispatch built-in events, such as `submit`, `click`, `change`, ...

I write `form.on('submit', function(){})` to hanlde form submitting event. Then, I want to dispatch submit form by clicking on an X element.

```
X.on('click', function(){
    // dispatch form submit here
});
```

P/s: I'm using PrototyeJS

Comment: Have you tried `dispatchEvent` with the name of a built-in event type?

Comment: @Bergi `dispatchEvent` doesn't accept string as parammeter's value

Comment: Then what is the `element.dispatchEvent('custom-event')` that you used?

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I just edited my question, it should be `element.dispatchEvent(custom_event)`

Comment: @Bergi the `simulate` works fine. Hope a built-in way came realy soon. Thank you.